# Is it possible to use “Google Sign in” in Xamarin.iOS and UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, xamarin.ios, google-signin

Is it possible to use Google Sign in in Xamarin.iOS and UWP apps? And does anyone do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn nuget package and everything else is done like in iOS integration tutorial. Regarding to UWP things are not so nice: you have to manually parse responses.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I can't (13 hours left). The funny thing - I've found info and implemented Google sign-in in all my apps  much faster than received answer from your MSFT support. I asked is sign-in functionality free for developer (like in google). As you can image they are still answering (2 leters received) that they will ask another department :) Happy that I didn't chose MSFT variant! :)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS use the [Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/tree/main/source/Google/SignIn) NuGet package and

```
using GIDSignIn = Google.SignIn.SignIn;
```